# not able to assign value in session-asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, session

just trying to learn asp.net
i am able to login and redirect to default.aspx.
i am trying to check if user's usere name and password are right from database(able to do).
now i am trying to store user name in session(not able to do, here i am getting nullpointer/value error) and show this session value as welcome message on next page/redirected page.my code is as:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx-pc\\ddd;Initial Catalog=db_Login;User Id=sd;Password=ds;");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select password from tab_userinformation where Username='" + txt_uname.Text + "'", con);
    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();

        if (dr[0].ToString() == txt_pwd.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
            //Response.Redirect("erp.htm");
            Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text;
```

here i am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object exception for Session["user"]

any suggestion
Thanks!

Comment: null pointer exception in C#?

Comment: The title and beginning of your post got nothing to do with your actual error and problem - highly confusing.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - the title may not be as clear as possible, but I think it is accurate of the issue.

Comment: Anyhow - what is `txt_uname`? Is it defined in the `.aspx` page? Note that C# is case sensitive, so if you named the TextBox as `txt_Uname` it won't work as it's totally different ID than `txt_uname`.

Comment: @Tim - no. The actual problem here is the Null Reference exception. After solving this, we can move on the other problems.

Comment: Don't use the text from the textbox in the sql string (see SQL Injection). Use parameters instead.

Comment: Who keeps teaching people this SQL concatenation! Arg

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - you're right.  Sorry - I think I should call it a night and get sleep.  I'm starting to miss the obvious.

Comment: sory guys for not able to elaborate properly thanks for pointing to mistake...

Comment: @phill-no body tought me trying my self if some thing wrong u can suggest me:). i have already said just trying myself to learn! i have hardcoded that sql concation just to test if connections are proper will use web.config setting letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the value in your Session before the Redirect:

```
Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text;
Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
```

That way you don't lose the value of txtuname.Text.

Also, you should use parameterized queries for your SQL - the way you currently have it, you are open to SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: You also shouldn't store your passwords in clear text, which it looks like you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

Because before assigning value to session, you are redirecting to another page.

```
Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
//Response.Redirect("erp.htm");
Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text; // this is not executing...
```

You have to assign value before redirecting to page. e.g.

```
Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text; // this is not executing...
Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
//Response.Redirect("erp.htm");
```

Comment: this needs to be fixed. but he might get the error at `SqlCommand` itself and so this might not solve it. IMO, he wont get an runtime error for a line not executing.

Comment: Correct, but relevant only for the future after solving the current error. (You probably didn't read the last couple of lines..)

Comment: @muhammad-thanks for understanding my dump question and elaborating it

Answer (score 1):

Check:

- In aspx there is a text control which has id = "txt_uname"
- Make sure this text control has runtat = server.

Comment: Yes, on my page cs file i can have a `TextBox txt_uname` and if I dont have any corresponding server side control in my aspx, this variable will be null at runtime

Comment: for that you will get `use of unassigned local variable "txt_uname"` error and it its initialised the code will run!

Answer (score 0):

The above code should be like this:

```
if (dr[0].ToString() == txt_pwd.Text)
    {
        Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text;
        Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
```

this would work. Once you redirect to some other page, control doesn't return to the statements after the "redirec". Hence they aren't executed. Instead statements inside page load of "default_Page" would start executing

Answer (score 0):

The statements after  **Response.Redirect()** wont be executed because this (Redirect) method transfer a user to another page.

Suggestion: Don't use hard-coded sql string. Use parameterized sql statements or stored-procedures.

```
string password=string.Empty;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx-pc\\ddd;Initial Catalog=db_Login;User Id=sd;Password=ds;"))
{
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select password from tab_userinformation where Username=@p1", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",txt_uname.Text);
        con.Open();
        object retValue=com.ExecuteScalar();
        if(retValue!=null)
        {
            password=retValue.ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    if (password== txt_pwd.Text)
    {
        Session["user"] = txt_uname.Text;
        Response.Redirect("default_Page.aspx");
    }

}
```